# C# Store values in static dictionary

Tags: c#, jquery, dictionary

I have this code , and i want to store values of parameters left, top in static dictionary. and after storing this values i want to access them in Jquery.Thanks For your Help.

my code

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.MoveShape
{
    public class MoveShapeHub : Hub
    {
        public void calculate(string left, string top)
        {
            Clients.Others.updateshape(left, top);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A "static dictionary" that appears to deal with user-related state sounds like a **really** bad idea in a web-server application...

Comment: I do not really understand the question 'cuz I'd think to store values in static `Dictionary` and to access data using jQuery are two things, they are not necessarily be coupled.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Mr. Gravell's answer works, are there something more I can help .. ?

Comment: @Jat.net if something is lacking, you should clarify (edit) the question to give people more context on the problem

Comment: Thanks Marc, i have comment a link, please reffer to that link, that must helps to understand my question and problem with it

Comment: If the linked question has more detail about the real problem, then put it here; otherwise, your question becomes an XY problem.

Comment: Thanks Ken kin, Do you have any hangout or yahoo account where i can discuss with you about the whole problem..

Comment: @Jat.net: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42500/jat-net

Comment: @Ken Kin sorry please, You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.this is message from stack overflow...

Comment: @Jat.net: Now you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery operates client-side, so you can't talk to it directly. You have two options, then:

- request the value via http (perhaps using SignalR as a messaging layer, since you are referencing that)
- serialize the dictionary as JSON into the request

Fortunately, the latter is fairly trivial for most common types - here using Json.NET:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"foo", 123},
    {"bar", "abc"},
    {"blap", true}
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

which gives us the JSON:

```
{"foo":123,"bar":"abc","blap":true}
```

If you assign that into a variable in the `<script>`, then values can be referenced either as `obj.bar` or as `obj['bar']`. However: keep in mind that *all* values will be serialized if you do this - you may want to be more restrictive in terms of tracking which the client actually cares about (or should be allowed to know about).

---

Important point, though: if your "static dictionary" is actually a `static` dictionary, then please consider very carefully the impact of multiple users. `static` is a really good way to write a web-site that only scales to a single user.

Comment: I don't know why you want to go the `JsonConvert` way here. Using SignalR just needs a JS `updateShape` function and his code will work. SignalR takes care of serialisation, etc. The question is probably more about the user aspect.

Comment: @LasseEspeholt then I suggest expressing that (ideally with some form of illustration) in an answer

Comment: I would if I could, but I can't where I am currently.